# Why pass the dependencies to the viewmodel via the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, dependencies

I'm working through Google's Android blueprints MVVM-databinding example (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-databinding/)

And I noticed that the dependencies for the viewmodel are being passed via the fragment.

```
public static TaskDetailFragment newInstance(String taskId) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putString(ARGUMENT_TASK_ID, taskId);
    TaskDetailFragment fragment = new TaskDetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mViewModel.start(getArguments().getString(ARGUMENT_TASK_ID));
}
```

Couldn't the task id in the example above be passed into the constructor of the viewmodel? And the fragment be oblivious to the task id?

Could someone explain the purpose/benefit of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a ViewModel scoped to the Fragment that is just being created, which happens in `onCreate()`, no? You can't get `taskId` into `onCreate` without passing it to the Fragment via `arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

Android needs to be able to re-build your fragment at any point, from scratch. It only knows two things:

1. That your fragment has a default constructor
2. That your fragment can be passed an arguments Bundle

It can't know how to call an arbitrary constructor and what arguments to pass to that constructor. Nor can it know how to persist and restore those arguments.

The idea is that you put any initialization information into the arguments Bundle. When your activity + fragments are destroyed (because of say memory pressure), Android saves the arguments Bundle. If your activity + fragments are then recreated later, those same arguments are provided. A Bundle is special in that it implements `Parcelable` meaning Android knows how to turn it to pure bytes and back again.